# Realm DB : having multiple instances vs Single instance

Tags: android, realm

Android Realm DB allows to get multiple instances using Realm.getInstance(). What is the best practice out of these? :
1. To create a single instance (application scoped) and use it everywhere
2. To get a new instance whenever required and close it when done , with one connection always being open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realm has internal caching, so the easiest approach is just to call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` when you need it can close it afterwards.

You can also read more about controlling the lifecycle here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

Comment: Additionally, having a single application-scoped instance means you must _always_ access that Realm instance from the UI thread. If you get an instance when you need it, you can write to that instance from a background thread.